# Zomato API: How to include multiple establishments in the search?

Tags: android, zomato-api

When you want to search you have to generate this URL `https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?
    lat=LATITUDE
    &lon=LONGITUDE
    &radius=RADIUS
    &establishment_type=ESTABLISHMENT IDS
    &category=3%2C10`

You can filter by putting multiple categories (in my case, I put "3,10") but whenever I do the same for the establishment types, it's like the API ignored it and showed all the results it could get.

Is there a way to filter the results using multiple establishment IDs?

Answer (score 1):

Zomato API follows the methodology where a user can only search for one Establishment type at a time. On the contrary, you can select/call multiple cuisines from API as well as App/Web.

Your suggestion is appreciated :)